# Having trouble keeping hyperlink style specific to one class/ id

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a different hyper link style to the following two things:

- Any links within `<p>` tags in my `#currentpage_content` div id.
- Any links with `<h3>` tags with a `.profile` class.

It sounds pretty simple but i can't see to get it right..

I've tried things like:

```
#currentpage_content a:hover{...}
```

and

```
#currentpage_content p a:hover{...}
```

but for some reason that applied to my navigation bar links even though they're outside #currentpage_content's div!

I also eventually figured out you could do something like this ( i think)..

```
#currentpage_content a.p:hover{...}
```

but now the link style aren't being applied at all when they should be.

Could someone please look at the bullet points above and tell me the exact syntax/order of words i need to achieve those two bullet points?

To make response easier here's the style i'm trying to apply:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active
{
font: inherit;
color: Grey;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #d4ffaa;
}
a:hover, a:active
{background-color: #d4ffaa;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/j2dkm/5) is a fiddle with solution for your trouble.

Comment: Ah thank you! i didn't realise i had to put the full term after each comma! doh

Answer (score 3):

```
#currentpage_content p a:hover, #currentpage_content h3 a:hover {
  //put your CSS in here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i forgot to mention i tried that too! but its definitely applying it to link outside the currentpage_content div! Trying to recreate it in a jsfiddle for example right now..

Comment: @Holly are you sure it's applying it outside the currentpage_content div when you use the exact code above? It shouldn't be, unless it's some really strange browser quirk. Will keep my eye out for your jsfiddle.

Comment: Ah disregard that, sorry it was a typo of mine! your answer is correct, thank you for taking the time!